# Java constructor ignore exception

Tags: java, constructor

in Java how do you ignore exceptions thrown from setters ? eg

I have a setter like this:

```
public setValue( double value){
    try{ 
     // trying to see if its a double. if it is, set private variable
     // 
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      //i want to catch if its not a double, then i set private varieble
      // to default value. 
    }
}
```

in constructor how to ignore exception if i use setValue() with an invalid value? ie i don't want to show any exception to the calling code. If i don't do any printstacktrace() will it be ok? How can i test for a double , no matter whether it comes in as a "string" or a real double? thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If the value is invalid, you should _want_ to get out an exception from the caller of `setValue`, which is more likely to have a sensible way of dealing with it.

Comment: Think of it this way: If the call has an invalid value, you want to throw the exception *now*, rather than stagger along. If you do the latter, then that just makes it that much harder to debug for the user (because now he/she has to trace through all of the "staggering" to find the actual issue).

Comment: Given the setter code you posted, you'd never see an exception calling it from anywhere, unless the omitted code in the catch block rethrows the caught exception, in which case why are you catching `Exception` there in the first place?

Comment: thanks. haev edited my question. basically just want to try and test a value, catch if invalid, and set to some default value if invalid.

Comment: @dorothy: check out my answer, does exactly that.

Comment: Well, you could simply put a try/catch in the constructor.

Comment: But note that there's no way to pass a `String` where the parameter is defined to be a `double`.  The code simply won't compile.

Comment: hi Hot Licks, normally how to just check if its double, no matter what data type it originate from? I guess i can use a if else to go through each possible data type ?

Comment: @dorothy If you just want to check if it's a double, you don't need that check. If the argument to `setValue` isn't a double, the code won't even *compile*.

Comment: hi Dennis Meng, the argument is most likely passed by user input. thanks

Comment: Dorothy, you're failing to understand.  If a parameter to a method is described as `double` then that's *all* the caller can pass.  Worst case it would be `Inf` or `NaN`, but it would still be an IEEE format `double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this . Based on your question.

```
//doubleVal is the value you are looking to set.
public void setValue(...) {
    try {
        // set the field
       doubleVal = Double.parseDouble(inputvalue);
    } catch ( NumberFormatException  e) {
        doubleVal=0.0;//default
    }
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to just *ignore* the exception. An alternative would be to return a boolean which indicates whether the field was set successfully:

```
public boolean setValue(...) {
    try {
        // set the field
        return true;
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or, if it makes more sense, you can also pass the exception back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i test for a double , no matter whether it comes in as a
>   "string" or a real double?

```
public setValue( double value){
    // Did this method compile?
    // Then the double must be valid!
    ...
```